# Convert from std::vector<std::vector<float>> to float**

Tags: c++, vector

There is a function which takes a `float**` parameter.
I have the values in a variable of type `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`.

Is it possible to make such a conversion without allocating a temporary `float*[]` ?

Comment: Yes it is. What have you tried ? It's simply a matter of allocating memory and then using 2 for loops and iterate through both vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly, but you don't have to copy the data from the "inner" vectors. Instead, you can create an array of pointers to the `data()` attributes of each inner vector.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> source;

std::vector<float*> target(source.size());
for (int i = 0; i < source.size(); ++i)
  target[i] = &*source[i].begin();
```

As you see you do not need to copy the inner `std::vector<>`s but you need to recreate the outer. A `std::vector<>` guarantees linear storage of its members (meaning it is compatible with a C-array) so it works for the inner vectors.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `std::vector` for `target`?

Comment: @avakar you are correct, you should use std::vector for target aswell

Comment: Watch the edge case - if any of the inner vectors is empty then `&*source[i].begin()` has undefined behavior. But since the function takes `float**` quite likely it expects rectangular data, and so hopefully that's what the questioner has.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the conversion by hand, by filling your `float**` with the values of `vector<vector<float> >` with two loops.

You will have to allocate the inner `float*` in any case.